# Banner does not display after completing payment process - javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue displaying my banner after completing payment in stripe. Basically after payment, the url dispalys a param of success and it either = true or false based on the payment status. The url seems correct and acts as it should but the banner does not display and I can't seem to know why that is after attempting to move the relevant block of code around in my javascript.

Any ideas?

```
     <div id="stripe-info-success">Your payment was successful
    <span class='close'>x</span>
  </div>
   <div id="stripe-info-failure">
    Your payment was cancelled
  <span class='close'>x</span>
</div> 
<button type="button" class="custombtn" id="checkout-button-sku_xxx" role="link">Retake Online Examination</button>


 <script>
(function() {
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxx');

  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-sku_xxx');
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
    // them to Checkout.
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{sku: 'sku_xxx', quantity: 1}],

      // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
      // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
      // a successful payment.
      // Instead use one of the strategies described in
      // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
      successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.metis-online.com/home?success=true',
      cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.metis-online.com/home?success=false',

    })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
      }

                               let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let success = url.searchParams.get("success");
if(success) {
  document.getElementById('stripe-info-success').classList.add('visible')
} else{
  document.getElementById('stripe-info-failure').classList.add('visible')
}
    });
  });
})();        


window.onload = function(){
var label = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
for (var i = 0; i<label.length; i++) {
  label[i].onclick = function () {
  var el = (this.parentNode);
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  };
}
};

    </script>
```

Comment: If(success) are you sure it’s a Boolean. Try hard coding as success = true;

Comment: Have you already tried manually running the code block in the dev tools console?

Comment: @swimmerF Ok to so when I run this block of code in the console as alive expression, it shows the banner: `let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let success = url.searchParams.get("success");
if(success) {
  document.getElementById('stripe-info-success').classList.add('visible')
} else{
  document.getElementById('stripe-info-failure').classList.add('visible')
}`

Comment: @SwimmerF It also gives me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'url' has already been declared at <anonymous> 1:!. Don't know if that is an issue or just because of the way I pasted the code

Comment: If the banner does show, the problem lies most likely with the timing the function is called. Something that often happens is that you attempt to add a class to an element before it has been created. The go-to hack for that is adding a timeout, the proper solution would be writing code that checks for the element before adding the class.